# Jquery UI Autocomplete in codeigniter using table oracle

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, autocomplete

views.php

```
<div class="input-group">
<input class="form-control" id="nomor_cari" maxlength="16" placeholder="No. CM / No. KTP">
```

script autocomplete

```
    $('#nomor_cari').autocomplete({
        source: get_no,
        dataType: 'JSON'
    });
```

function get_no

```
<?php
        function get_no($q)
    {
        $this->db->select('NO_MEDREC');
        $this->db->like('NO_MEDREC', $q);
        $query = $this->db->get('PASIEN_IRJ');
        if($query->num_rows > 0)
        {
            foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
            {
                $row_set[] = htmlentities(ucfirst($row['NO_MEDREC'])); 
            }
            $this->output
                    ->set_content_type('application/json')
                    ->set_output(json_encode($row_set)); 
        }
        echo $query->row();
    }?>
```

but autocomplete didn't show anything.

if i use local variable , autocomplete works like it should be.

```
<script> var availableNumber = [
        "0000000002",
        "0000000020",
        "0000000200",
        "0000002000"
    ];
/<script>
```

and changes autocomplete to

```
        $('#nomor_cari').autocomplete({
        source: availableNumber,
        dataType: 'JSON'
    });
```

what did i missed? (im sure .js are loaded because when using local var , it works like charm)

just in case needed , here's my autoload

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'email', 'session');
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'template', 'message', 'misc');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think issue is in "source". Please try to use json like this

```
$('#nomor_cari').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.getJSON("ful_url/get_no?term=" + request.term, function (data) {
            response($.map(data.dealers, function (value, key) {
                return {
                    label: value,
                    value: key
                };
            }));
        });
    },
});
```